# Modify DacPac Using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dacpac

I need to read existing dacpac using powershell and change schema then replicate the database. Is there any possibility to use "`System.Reflection`"

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why would the `System.Reflection` namespace be of interest?

Comment: I tried to create dacpac using powershell. And upgrade the database using poweshell. I have database with multiple schema's. I need to replicate the tables,functions,sp...etc to each schema.

Comment: Why using powershell? Any reason not to use SqlPackage.exe?

Comment: @qxg,  because i need to do an automation. thankz for your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a full public API that supports loading dacpacs, reading the contents (tables, views etc. in the schema), and adding / updating these contents before saving back. The samples project is at https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions, with a tutorial explaining core concepts [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2013/12/23/dacfx-public-model-tutorial/). There are a number of additional examples, such as [Ed Elliott's blog](https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/HOWTO-Filter-Dacpac-Deployments) and open source contributions that can help you understand what to do.

Disclosure: I work on the DacFx team and wrote the linked tutorial.

Comment: This is really helpful. anyway  i need to do same thing using powershell

Comment: You can use these APIs in Powershell. Either code directly against these APIs or write a command line wrapper, whichever is your preference. There are no built-in cmdlets that support these.

Comment: Thankz for your help. (Y)